# Can you have multiple products pull from single inventory?

Tags: shopify

We have two products:

Coffee Beans & Coffee Mugs

Each has multiple variations (pictures on the front) but our inventory for coffee beans and coffee mugs aren't dependent on the variations. There is a total inventory for mugs and a total inventory for beans.

Is it possible in Shopify to have the beans or mugs pull from a collective inventory? If so -- how do you set that up?

**Any information is greatly appreciated!**

Comment: If your inventory is not dependent on the variations(Product options and variants)
Then you can use "product attributes" for the multiple variations. But this is valid if your prices is also does not depend on the variations.

Comment: Mani, do you have a link you can point me to referencing this? Not sure if it's what we need or not. Thank you!